# while loop is not breaking even after condition met

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, exception, try-catch

```
row_group = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainPanel"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody')))

with open('testfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)
    wr.writerow(header)
    while True:
        for row in row_group.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr'):
            wr.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td')])
            time.sleep(4)
        print(f"Processing page ..")
        time.sleep(4)
        try:
            next_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ant-pagination-next")))
            next_link.click()
            time.sleep(4)
        except:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                                            '#mainPanel > div > div > div.rc-tabs-content.rc-tabs-content-animated > div.rc-tabs-tabpane.rc-tabs-tabpane-active > div.chip-body > div > div > ul > li.ant-pagination-next.ant-pagination-disabled')))
            print('no more pages left')

            break
```

this my code after the button is disable  code is not coming out of the loop continually[[this selector details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvWqv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb2s8.png) scraping same page

Answer (score 1):

I can't debug your code, but I guess your code doesn't reach the `break` line because it fails and throws an exception on previous line:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#mainPanel > div > div > div.rc-tabs-content.rc-tabs-content-animated > div.rc-tabs-tabpane.rc-tabs-tabpane-active > div.chip-body > div > div > ul > li.ant-pagination-next.ant-pagination-disabled')))
```

Generally, it's not correct to put code that can throw an exception inside the `except` block without additional `try-except` mechanism.

Comment: Hi  i tried all possibilities with if class also could let me help me with this i try in selenium python , this is pagination xpath = //*[@id="mainPanel"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul , this next button  xpath = //*[@id="mainPanel"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[8] , this is button got disable class = class="ant-pagination-next ant-pagination-disabled", i  want when button got disable come out of loop and quit the driver  .Thanks in advance